# Android admob ads ruin layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-view

I am fairly new to android dev, and I am looking at implementing android admob ads into my app. I have never implemented ads before, so I was wondering if the ad squashes the layout on the screen or if it simply overlays over the other items such as imageviews etc. I am worried because I would like an ad on the bottom and if it doesnt overlay it will screw up the whole positioning of my pages. Would anyone know the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user, I have seen admob ads which overlay the screen.

<sub>I swear at them every time they block the corner of the screen I need to see in Angry Birds.</sub>